# Program does action two times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in Unity. I made some code that gives you in game money every second but when i play my project, there is a bug that gives you money two times.
How can i fix this. Maybe it has to do with the static variables i use but i would like help. Thank you.

this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public static int soldiers;
    [SerializeField]
    public static int money;
    [SerializeField]
    public static int income;

    private int nextUpdate = 1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        income = 500;
        money = 2500;
        soldiers = 20;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Time.time >= nextUpdate)
        {
            nextUpdate = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time) + 1;
            UpdateEverySecond();
        }
    }

    void UpdateEverySecond()
    {
        GetMoney();
        DecreaseIncome();
    }


    void GetMoney()
    {
        money += income;
    }

    void DecreaseIncome()
    {
        if (income >= 0)
        {
            income -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this script in the scene more than once? Can you describe the behavior with some more details?

Comment: Could you also explain why you made those variables `static`? Generally speaking having mutable `static` variables that get modified from (potentially) more than one instance can cause a lot of problems

Comment: If not an extra instance of the script, maybe it's a timing issue - try using a 1 second coroutine instead

Comment: Don't use `static`s in Unity 3D for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592063/585968) and [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675616/how-to-detect-know-when-object-have-been-deleted-from-the-hierarchy-in-editor-or#comment128373584_72675616).  Apart from that, in your particular issue it will just mean all instances of `PlayerStats` will share the same _state_, at least the parts marked `static`.

Comment: Your `Update()` looks fine.  BTW **kudos** for using `Timer` instead of horrid coroutines.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I checked and the script is not more than once in the scene. The Script uses monobehavior but some script use PlayerStats instead of monobehavior to access variables from PlayerStats.

Comment: @UnholySheep i made the variables static to access them in other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in another script that used PlayerStats instead of monobehavior and somehow it just dubled everything that the class PlayerStats did.